# Problem when adding a MySQL enum column via ruby Rails migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, rails-migrations

I'm trying to add a MySQL enum column by doing:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class AddStatusToTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
        ALTER TABLE tasks ADD status enum('to_do', 'doing', 'done');
    SQL
  end
  def down
    remove_column :tasks, :status
  end
end
```

But I get the error:

```
AddStatusToTasks: migrating =================================
-- execute("        ALTER TABLE tasks ADD status enum('to_do', 'doing', 'done');\n")
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: near "'to_do'": syntax error
```

My model likes looks like:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  enum status: { to_do: 'to_do', doing: 'doing', done: 'done' }
end
```

I'm actually following the guide [here](https://sipsandbits.com/2018/04/30/using-database-native-enums-with-rails/), but I can't find the problem.

Thanks everybody in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQLite3::SQLException` -- you are executing this query on a SQLite database, not MySQL. Are you using the correct environment?